# C++ ASCII game map

Tags: c++

I made a simple map and almost everything works fine.
Anyway, I can't figure out how to restrict player (@) from going outside a map.
I tried it with if statements but this doesn't work correctly and program crash when player(@) walks outside a map.

```
if (input == 's' && y < HEIGHT) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        y++;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
    if (input == 'e' && x < WIDTH) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        x++;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
    if (input == 'n' && y >= 0){
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        y--;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }

    if (input == 'w' && x >= 0) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        x--;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
```

---

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

const int HEIGHT = 15, WIDTH = 30;
int x = 0, y = 0; //Primary player coordinates...global :-O

void GrassColor() {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
}

void NormalColor() {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
}

void BlueColor() {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
}

void RedColor() {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
}

char myMap[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '~', '.', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '~', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' }
};

void PrintMap() {
    cout << "(" << x << ','<< y << ")" << endl;
    GrassColor();
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            if (myMap[i][j] == '.') {
                GrassColor();
                cout << myMap[i][j];
            }
            else if (myMap[i][j] == '~'){
                BlueColor();
                cout << myMap[i][j];
            }
            else if (myMap[i][j] == '@') {
                RedColor();
                cout << myMap[i][j];
            }
            else{
                NormalColor();
                cout << myMap[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    NormalColor();
}

int main() {
    char input; //For user input.
    char temp_tile = myMap[y][x]; // '.' (0, 0);
    myMap[y][x] = '@'; // '@' (0, 0);
    PrintMap(); 

while (true) {
    cin >> input;

    if (input == 's' && y < HEIGHT) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        y++;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
    if (input == 'e' && x < WIDTH) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        x++;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
    if (input == 'n' && y >= 0){
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        y--;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }

    if (input == 'w' && x >= 0) {
        myMap[y][x] = temp_tile;
        x--;
        temp_tile = myMap[y][x];
        myMap[y][x] = '@';
        PrintMap();
    }
}
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your conditions check whether the player wants to move and is already in the map. They should check whether the player wants to move and is not on the border of the map. (currently, you can move in any direction as long as you're already in the map, but it doesn't prevent you from going out of the map)

Comment: Note that it may be common to surround the map with *wall* to simplify the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (input == 's' && y < HEIGHT)
```

This test (`y < HEIGHT`) is wrong. The bottom-most y coordinate should be `HEIGHT - 1`. So if the player's y position is not less than `HEIGHT - 1`, he should be stopped from moving south. Likewise, all the other tests are off by one as well. So:

```
if (input == 's' && y < HEIGHT) -> if (input == 's' && y < HEIGHT - 1)
if (input == 'e' && x < WIDTH)  -> if (input == 'e' && x < WIDTH - 1)
if (input == 'n' && y >= 0)     -> if (input == 'n' && y > 0)
if (input == 'w' && x >= 0)     -> if (input == 'w' && x > 0)
```